# Composer will not use forked installers lib

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to setup Composer to automatically install modules, themes, and extensions into a site using the Yii framework.  The documentation on the Composer website says to use a custom installer type for this purpose (http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md).  I checked the composer/installers lib on GitHub (https://github.com/composer/installers), and saw that it did not natively support Yii.  I then proceeded to fork this repository and add it in myself, but I cannot for the life of me get composer to use my forked composer/installers.  My composer.json looks like the following:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "https://github.com/mattamatic/installers"
        }
    ],

    "name": "dmg/yii-theme-ace",
    "type": "yii-theme",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just read http://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/why-can%27t-composer-load-repositories-recursively.md, turned out I needed to have the custom repository defined in the root composer.json.